# Adding a delay in my code, not working. C++

Tags: windows, winforms, c++-cli, delay

Trying to make simon says game as my semester project, problem is I cant add a delay between the colors when they change,
i.e i want to add a delay so that when one box color changes, then after about 3~4 seconds the next box color changes, but the problem is **when I put the Sleep() in my for loop, the system pauses for the amount given as a whole, then displays all the colors changed at the same time not one by one**....

Any help, here is the function that i call when the game's start button is clicked. How to fix it ?

```
void flash()
    {
        srand(time(NULL));

        int x;
        for (int i = 5; i > 0;i--)
        {
            x = rand() % 4;

            if (x == 0)
            {
                button1->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Blue;
            }
            else if (x == 1)
            {
                button2->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Blue;
            }
            else    if (x == 2)
            {
                button3->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Blue;
            }
            else    if (x == 3)
            {
                button4->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Blue;
            }
            Sleep(500);
        }
    }
```

P.s I have tried to put the sleep in the if statements but that doesn't work either, Any help please ?

Comment: You need to refresh the view somehow. Need more info on the UI framework you're using.

Comment: @Nattrass: it's just poor formatting - the Sleep is actually inside the for loop.

Comment: Refresh() button control after each change but it's NOT right way to do these things. UI  will freeze. Start a Task, sleep and dispatch color change to ui thread. Btw...aby reason to mix NET and CRT?

Comment: @MarcoA. .  Well im working on windows form application in C++, and i have just programming, first semester, and this is a project. + im a noob ._.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, so i should add Refresh() button after each change to refresh the UI ?
The reason im using CRT is that our teacher told us to make the game on it, using the buttons which are already premade in it.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, what you mean by Start a Task, sleep and dispatch color change to ui thread ? :|
Forgive me for being a noob at this..

Comment: I do not know your teacher but mixing c++ and c++/cli is REALLY strange if you are not doing interop stuff. Even more strange than mixing c lib with c++ lib!

Comment: I mean: better way is to start an async task (with Task::Run) and Thread::Sleep inside it then dispatch color change with this->BeginInvoke (because in winforms ui must be accessed by main thread). In this way ui won't block even if you sleep 10 seconds. Ok, I oversimplified some concept little bit...but I'd guess your teacher told you about this (otherwise your homework has little sense, IMO).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: Or just use async with the UI dispatcher.  `Task::Delay` is designed for async Tasks, best to forget that `Thread::Sleep` even exists.

Comment: @Ben absolutely, just trying to keep it as "low" as possible. In reality I would have a separate class for such scheduled operations

Answer (score 0):

As your code is single-treaded and you are updating the colors of the buttons in a loop, there is (currently) no chance for the application's standard drawing routines to kick in, until the loop is finished. If you do want a redraw while being in the loop, you have to manually issue it by (e.g.):

```
button1->Invalidate();
button1->Update();
```

Please be aware that, if you stay in the loop for too long, windows does recognize that your application is not responding to windows messages and renders it "unresponsive" (window fading to half white). To circumvent this, you can use the Timer class from System::Windows::Forms to implement the delay behaviour.